# Transferring iOS App Between Orgs - APNS and Certs

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, ios-provisioning

Must move 2 apps to a different enterprise org. I am gathering all the information I think I need and following guidelines that I found at [App transfer overview](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f).

I don't understand the documentation concerning these 4 items.

1. Bundle Id
2. Provisioning profile
3. APNS Certificate (If push notifications implemented for app)
4. Account Certificate (These are developer account specific, means unique for all the app published under same account)

The bundle ID will not change so no problem there.
Understand that #2 and #4 will have to be recreated when we want to do our next update.

So what about APNS certs? As they are associated with the previous org's account, I don't think these will work any longer. But if that is true and we have to make a new APNS in the new Org wouldn't we have to attach it the app and thus push out a new build?

Clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: The apns certificate is used by your server to authenticate to the Apple push server.  It isn't in the app. You will need to make a new apns certificate but as long as the apns certificate and the target push token are associated with the same developer account the push will work.

Comment: Paul, this is still not clear to me. I think what you are saying is the APNS is not associated with the app, it is not hooked in the app. When an app tries to send a push notification, it looks at the developer account that owns the app to see if there is a valid APNS. If there is then no problem. So we can just create an APNS right after the app is moved to the new developer account and we will be good.